# DISTINCT or GROUP BY not working. Not sure which

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I am having a problem with a query where I am using a DISTINCT and a GROUP BY and still receiving duplicate rows for the row in question. GBelow is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ms.id AS ms_id, ms.identity, ms.timezone, ms.language,
 ms.country, ms.dst, ms.mobile, ms.voice, ms.email,  ms.firstname, ms.lastname, ms.gender, ms.address_1,
 ms.address_2, ms.city, ms.state, ms.zipcode, ms.dateofbirth,
  ms.custom_field_1, ms.custom_field_2, ms.custom_field_3, ms.custom_field_4,
 ms.custom_field_5, ms.carrier, ms.stamp AS ms_stamp,
  ss.id AS ss_id, ss.last_response_text, ss.stamp AS ss_stamp,
 c.id AS c_id, c.name, c.stamp AS c_stamp,
 c.messenger_account, c.keyword, c.community, ms.hash
 FROM tbl_messenger_subscriber_session ss
 JOIN tbl_messenger_subscriber ms ON ss.subscriber = ms.id
 LEFT JOIN tbl_messenger_subscriber_category c ON c.id = ss.subscriber_category
 WHERE ms.custom_field_1 = 'Middlesex' AND ss.subscriber_category IN ('23607','23634')
GROUP BY ms_id, c.messenger_account
```

And the output looks something like this

```
ms_id   | other columns
1636088 | xxxxxxxxxxxx
1636088 | xxxxxxxxxxxx
1636090 | xxxxxxxxxxxx
1636090 | xxxxxxxxxxxx
1636336 | xxxxxxxxxxxx
1636337 | xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And the expected output looks something like this

```
ms_id   | other columns
1636088 | xxxxxxxxxxxx
1636090 | xxxxxxxxxxxx
1636336 | xxxxxxxxxxxx
1636337 | xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong in my query for the DISTINCT and GROUP BY to not work as expected?

Comment: You `GROUP BY ms_id, c.messenger_account` and not `GROUP BY ms_id` so you don't get duplicates for the combination of `ms_id, c.messenger_account`

Comment: You should not be using group by since you are not aggregating and distinct applies over all columns in the select and with all those columns I suspect there is no distinctness . You need to define what you mean by duplicate and provide sample data an expected output.

Comment: I've added my expected output

Comment: forpas, your solution works, but I need to think if there is a reason if I had the group by c.messenger_account there

Comment: Using group by in your case is not a solution, because you get arbitrary values for all the other columns. Just rethink what you want to do.

Comment: Which MySQL version? Perhaps you need to a use a _window function_.

Comment: jarlh, Version 5.6

Comment: forpas, if there was a reason for adding c.messenger_account to the group by I can't remember it, if you make your comment an answer, I can make it the chosen answer.

Comment: This case is addressed in many questions in SO. There is no need for another duplicate answer.